# FormUrlEncode returns unexpected result encoding the º(masculine ordinal indicator)

Tags: c#, urlencode

I have a program that comunicates with an external http server to the request a first, second etc value...  (`1º`,`2º`,`3º`,`4º`,...)

I have an issue in c# with the `º` character.

Here is some example code:

```
var testdata=new Dictionary<string,string>{
    {"val","º"},
    {"val1","\xBA"},
    {"val2","\u00BA"},
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(testdata);
var cont = content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

the result is:

```
val=%C2%BA&val1=%C2%BA&val2=%C2%BA
```

I test the communication with the server with curl and firefox console
and the result should be:

```
val=%BA&val1=%BA&val2=%BA
```

Somehow the extra `%C2` in C# dosent work with the server.

How can I fix or escape the `º` correctly?

Comment: See how a little effort made this question so much nicer? The problems here went beyond just English language issues. You should generally expect that we'll put the same effort into our responses that you put into your question.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn sorry but the english is not my language, I'ts not my effort is what i know.

Comment: A lot of what I fixed had nothing to do with English vs other languages.

Comment: Gracias amigo asi aprendo un poco, the htpp,  and mus I know write well  the other think you learn me how to do well and thanks, anyway I use must when comes should , ej: use comunicate i do the mistake because is one program only and in my language Use the S to plural , You can also correct me this comment that I put the same effort ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue  relates with the default encoding used by `FormUrlEncodedContent` which is `UTF-8` and your server expect `ISO-8859-1`.

Here is a workaround to get over it but you'll need (unfortunately) to add `System.Web` to your project :

```
// This is an implementation of FormUrlEncodedContent with `ISO-8859-1`
public class FormIso8859Encoder : ByteArrayContent
{
    public FormIso8859Encoder(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection) 
         : base(FormDataToByteArray(nameValueCollection))
    {
         Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    }

    private static byte[] FormDataToByteArray(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var nameValue in nameValueCollection)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append('&');

            sb.Append(nameValue.Key);
            sb.Append('=');

            // Here is the major change
            sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nameValue.Value, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") ));
        }

        return Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then

```
var testdata=new Dictionary<string,string>{
    {"val","º"},
    {"val1","\xBA"},
    {"val2","\u00BA"},
};
var content = new FormIso8859Encoder(testdata);
var cont = content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This provide the following output :

```
val=%BA&val1=%BA&val2=%BA
```

Comment: a litle change is needed in the constructor to do the work  add: Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Answer (score 1):

The correct unicode character for `°` is `\u00B0`. More info can you find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx) how to work with unicode in C#.

All unicode characters can be found [here](http://unicode-table.com).

Comment: I use the \u00BA masculine ordinal indicator the unicode is rigth